# iOS/Swift: How to implement doubletap action for backButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to implement a custom back button for every ViewController in my app. I want it to have two actions. If the button gets single tapped, it should give toast warning. If the button gets double tapped it should go back to ViewController.

How can I achieve this for only the backbutton in swift?

Comment: IMHO I think this user experience would be counter intuitive. Perhaps you could re-think why would want this. Or have a view controller that is not pushed. Pushed view controllers have a user experience that users expect

Comment: UIButton or UIBarButton ?

Comment: Either programmatically or not doesnt matter, i have to acheive the task, Doesnt matter if using UIbutton

Comment: Duplicate of your own question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49627777/3207014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to Work with bar Button with single and Double Tap

```
/// Tap Gesture to Handle Double Tap
let tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(SourceVC.handleGesture(getsure:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

/// Custom Button That With Handle two actions
let customButtonn : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
customButtonn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
customButtonn.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
customButtonn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SourceVC.navButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
customButtonn.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

/// Create a Custom bar Button  
let navLeftButton = UIBarButtonItem()
navLeftButton.customView = customButtonn

/// Assign it to navigation Bar
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = navLeftButton
```

My custom Button Actions in SourceVC Class

```
/// Single Tap
@objc func navButton(sender:UIButton){
        print("navButtonTapped Once")
      }

/// Double Tap
@objc func handleGesture(getsure:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("navButtonTapped twice")
      }
```

Simulator Output:
[image]

Console output:
[image]

**Note -** Doing this will move default back occur with the bar and you need to design it custom way so it appear like that as Shown in Simulator output - button appear without that back image

Comment: Welcome, Happy To Help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the actions and behavior for BackBarButtonItem, what you can do is create a your own UIBarButtonObject and assign it as your leftBarButtonItem while giving it your own selector

One thing to note is that this will remove the stock back button image.

Comment: ok, can u guide me to acheive the task , if i made the button programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actingFunction))
    DoubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    barButton.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
```

Comment: You can't add a gesture to a `UIBarButtonItem`.